# Qu diferencia hay entre entre una instancia de Sql Server y el Nombre del servidor de Sql Server

Tags: servidor

1-Quisera saber esta diferencia entre el nombre del servidor que aparece en Sql Server Manegement Studio y la instancia que aparece En Sql Server Configuration Maneter

2- Y que es correcto poner en una cadena de conexión mas precisamente en DataSource el nombre del servidor de Server Manegement Studio o el nombre de la instancia de Sql Server Configuration Maneger.

Yo colocaba en la cadena de conexión el nombre del Servidor de SQL Server Manegement Studio solamente. Pero si la intancia es como otro sql server que se tiene en tu pc, ahi iria
****nombre de instancia\nombre del servidor** en la cadena de conexión?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los nombres de instancia **sólo se ponen** en las cadenas de conexión para las Instancias nombradas. La instancia por defecto en una instalación de MSSQL se llama creo que MSSQLSERVER **pero** no se usa. La cadena de conexión va sólo con el puerto y el databaseName

Comment: Si pero la difencia de instancia con el nombre del servidor de Manegement Studio cual es?.  Y me acuerdo que yo colocaba en la cadena de conexión en el data source el nombre del servidor que aparece en SQL Server Manegement Studio, la base de datos, el usuario y la contraseña , no colocaba un puerto y funcionaba bien.  Gracias

Comment: Ah, pues es que el nombre del servidor lo puede usar MSSQL para resolver vía WINS (NetBios) y no darle la IP. Dependiendo del ecosistema, eso puede no funcionar porque los mensajes NetBios pueden estar bloqueados; idealmente yo usaría siempre la IP (pero soy yo, habituado a conectarme por JDBC). Sobre la instancia, ya depende de cómo te conectas, que resuelva por defecto a una instancia y BD (y que use el puerto por defecto, pero que lo usa, lo usa así no te avise)